# What is leftover of MOX fuel after being burned in a fast reactor?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

My understanding is that basically the U-238 and P-239 play off each other and it can keep reacting essentially as long as the neutron density is enough. The U-238 that doesn't fission eventually becomes P-239 so the concentrations don't change much.

IS that correct? Does this cause a build-up of actinides or do those split with fast neutrons too?

Comment: You are correct that there is interplay between the U238 and Pu-239.  However, the details can get very complicated.  You can design the reactor to be a net producer of fissionable material, or you can design it to be a net destroyer of actnides.  Is there a specific application you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

In a fast breeder reactor the amount of Pu239 produced from transmutation of U238 exceeds the amount of Pu239 consumed in fission; this is called "breeding" Pu239.  (In the reactor, U238 captures a neutron and beta decays to Np239 which in turn beta decays to Pu239.)  However, even though more Pu239 is produced than in the initial fuel loading, neutron poisons build up from the fission fragments and their subsequent decay chains, and the reactor cannot be maintained in a critical state.  (Also, the mechanical integrity of the fuel elements degrades due to build-up of fission product gases and changes in the structure-phases- of the fuel element materials, and this requires removing the fuel.) Reprocessing of the spent fuel is required to separate out the Pu239 (and other non-fissile isotopes of Pu such as Pu240 created in the reactor) to then be combined with U238 as fresh fuel.  The actual Pu in the fuel is not pure Pu239 due to the presence of the other Pu isotopes that build up while in the reactor.  (The longer the fuel is left in the reactor the higher the percentage of non-Pu239 isotopes. For production of Pu for nuclear weapons in the old Hanford and Savannah River reactors, to have a high concentration of Pu239 the fuel was removed from the reactors for reprocessing after a relatively short time.) The spent fuel material left over after reprocessing is nuclear waste.

A fast neutron spectrum is required to breed Pu; that is to produce more Pu239 than is "burned" in fission.  A thermal reactor also produces Pu239 from the U238 using the same reactions as in a fast reactor, but for a thermal neutron spectrum the amount of Pu239 produced is less than the amount of Pu239 (or U235, depending on the initial fuel composition) burned in fission; this is called "converting" (to) Pu239. Thermal reactor fuel can also be reprocessed to recover the Pu239- that was converted from U238 in the reactor- and use it in fresh fuel.

Details of the neutron physics can be found in other questions and answers on this site if you search for "breeder".

Comment: So the products of fission interact with and slow down neutrons? Do you know how much U-240 is able to fission? I read that the average neutron energy released during fission is 2MeV which is right on that threshold which should trigger actual fission

Comment: Yes , for instance fission products can capture neutrons (neutron capture reaction) like all other elements.
240U is not known to be fissile and its half-life is only about 14 hours.
For 235U for example, there is no threshold energy required: on the contrary, the slower the neutron (hence the role of the neutron moderator-retarder), the greater the probability of capture and subsequent fission  is high.

Comment: There is some fissioning of non-fissile, fissionable, isotopes from high energy neutrons.  Suggest you look at the definitions of fissile, fissionable, and fertile.  See a text on nuclear engineering such as Nuclear Reactor Theory, or Introduction to Nuclear Engineering, both by Lamarsh.  Also see my answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/666892/how-is-fast-breeder-reactor-possible-when-u238-has-bigger-fast-neutron-cross-sec in this exchange.

Comment: Note that the question didn't use the term "breeder".  The OP is correct that there is interplay between U238 and Pu239.  However, the details are very complicated and depend on the application.  You can design the reactor to be a net producer of fissionable material, or you can design it to be a net destroyer actinides.  Is there a specific application that the OP had in mind?

Comment: @NuclearFission I'm thinking in terms of a burner with little regard for breeding. Mitigating waste. If I burned MOX what is leftover?

Comment: I am not familiar with a fast reactor burner.  Perhaps @NuclearFission can address this. My guess is that radionuclides in the waste from the fission products would still be of concern

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you start with a "vector" of different actinide number densities and you will end with a different vector of actinide densities plus some fission products. To find out exactly when the new vector will be, you need to run a computer code that models depletion.

Actinides can have different reactions, but the most common reactions in fast reactors are fission, neutron capture, and (n,2n). A fission reaction is the only way to destroy an actinide.  Neutron capture and (n,2n) reactions just transform one actinide to another. Some isotopes will also decay, which also creates different actinides.

One benefit of fast reactors is that the "fission to capture" ratio is higher than thermal reactors, so it is possible to be a net destroyer of actinides.  A thermal reactor will always produce more actinides above uranium than are destroyed.  One of the arguments to build fast reactors is be able to actually decrease the number of actinides and reduce the long-term radiotoxicity of nuclear waste.

Fission products are much more radioactive when the fuel is discharged, but they decay away quicker.  Actinides dominate the long-term radiotoxicity of the nuclear waste, so if you can reduce the number of actinides, you can decrease the amount of radiotoxicity over very long times.